# run php script in background so that user doesn't have to wait

Tags: php, shell, background, exec

i want php script to run in background so that the user does not have to wait for its completion if its a long process. I used the following code.

```
shell_exec("nohup php own.php > /dev/null & echo $!");
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I googled a lot but I was not able to come up with a solution.

Comment: have you tested your command on the command line direclty? Are you sure you web server is permitting shell exec to run and has the correct shell? For info I always prefer to use `exec` rather than `shell_exec` as it gives you the exit code of the command which is really critically useful I think

Comment: can u tell how to run on cl

Comment: you will need to SSH to your server and then paste that command in and hit return.

Comment: m running in mamp..how to do ssh

Comment: If running in mamp then you already have a command line, you are running locally so just open a terminal and paste your command in there

Answer (score 0):

You can also try proc(Program execution Functions) methods.

https://www.php.net/proc_open

If you are trying shell_exec() or exec() on ubuntu you need to install some of the libraries.